# angular/javascript parsing and getting only the value of paramMap

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

how do we get only the value from the router param map. right now the output is

```
 authkey:af408c30-d212-4efe-933d-54606709fa32
```

I only want the random `"af408c30-d212-4efe-933d-54606709fa32"` without the key `"authkey:"` how do we parse that in JavaScript ? or is there a way in angular to not include the key and just get the value. Thanks.

```
 this.router.paramMap.subscribe(paramMap => {
      this.authKey = paramMap.get('authkey')
    });
```

- current output : authkey:af408c30-d212-4efe-933d-54606709fa32
- desired output : af408c30-d212-4efe-933d-54606709fa32 , I want to exclude the authkey:.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just delete `authKey` from the retrieved string like so:

```
  this.authKey = paramMap.get('authkey').replace('authkey:', '')
```

Answer (score 1):

Angular is seeing everything as the authkey parameter. This is from the way you specify parameters in your Router Module. You should do some string manipulation to remove the "authkey:".

Do this:

```
this.authKey = paramMap.get('authkey').replace('authkey:', '')
```

Comment: suggestion : add code fences to highlight the code and make it better to read